# best way to transfer setparameters() on surfacechanged camera

Tags: android, camera

I'm playing around with android camera functions.  I'm trying to dynamically change the camera parameters using a menu `onCheck` and then calling the `surfaceChanged` to implement the changes.

```
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

            Camera.Parameters parameters = camera.getParameters();
            switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.EFFECT_AQUA:
                Toast.makeText(this, "AQUA", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                if (item.isChecked()) item.setChecked(false);
                else item.setChecked(true);
                parameters.setColorEffect(Camera.Parameters.EFFECT_AQUA);
                surfaceChanged(null, 0, 0,0);
                return true;

public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int w, int h) {
        Camera.Parameters parameters = camera.getParameters();
        camera.setParameters(parameters);
        camera.startPreview();
        }
```

when I run the app, checking the `menuItem` calls the `surfaceChanged` but the chosen parameters are not used/set by the setparamater command.

I was thinking of implementing a global to capture the changes but I don't like it.  Is there another way to transfer parameters when we do a `surfaceChanged` call?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the given code snippet I'd say you forgot to publish the changed parameters to the camera. If you don't call setParameters(Parameters parameters) on your Camera instance, the camera will utilize the former parameter settings.

`Camera.Parameters parameters = camera.getParameters();
parameters.setColorEffect(Camera.Parameters.EFFECT_AQUA);
camera.setParameters(parameters); // add this line to your code`

Comment: you should also check for getSupportedColorEffects